# Transparent Proxy for IPv6 traffic under Linux

Tags: linux, ipv6, nat

When maintaining networks, it is often an expedient thing to do to run a transparent proxy. By transparent proxy I mean a proxy that 'hijacks' outgoing connections and runs them through a local service. Specifically I run a linux firewall with squid configured so that all tcp/ip connections fowarded on port 80 are proxied by squid.

This is achived using the iptables 'nat' table, using IPv4.

But iptables for IPv6 does not have a 'nat' table, so I cannot use the same implementation. What is a technique I can use to transparently proxy traffic for IPv6 connections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A viable way to do this is with the TPROXY rule in iptables, documentation is available here:

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4#IPv6_Support
- http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt

This should be supported Squid (>= version 3.2). Using `--enable-linux-netfilter` and the `iptables -t mangle -j TPROXY` rule.

Answer (score 2):

iptables has a QUEUE target, which you can use to deliver packets to userspace.  I am not sure, but perhaps something could be implemented there.

Past that, you could take a stab at adding something to the kernel to do redirection.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Quoting from [squid-cache.org](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/IPv6):

> NAT simply does not exist in IPv6. By
>   Design.
>
> Given that transparency/interception
>   is actually a feature gained by
>   secretly twisting NAT routes inside
>   out and back on themselves. It's quite
>   logical that a protocol without NAT
>   cannot do transparency and
>   interception that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation:

http://www.suse.de/~krahmer/ip6nat/

Answer (score 0):

Another sort of ugly hack:

- MARK all traffic with iptables (seems, there is CONNMARK target for IPv6)
- route all marked traffic to tun device
- do user-space NAT in the daemon listening at tun device
- ...

Comment: Is this actually possible? Any idea where I'd start with a tun implementation with ipv6 support?

Comment: IMHO, it SHOULD be possible. Linux tun/tap driver seems to support IPv6. Try tap driver (virtual ethernet) instead of tun if I'm wrong and IPv6 is not supported.

I don't know what may be done with iptables `QUEUE`, but tun-based solution should work, though it may be unsuitable for highload.

Answer (score -3):

Write your own implementation of NAT in IPv6 stack.